# Assign a vector to the last row of a matrix: MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, vector

I want to replace the last row of a matrix with a vector.

For example, I did the following and got the error shown:

```
L = [1 2 3
     4 5 6
     4 6 7]

J = [1 4 6]

K = L(end,:)=J
K == find(L(:,end)=J)
                  ↑
Error: The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target for an assignment
```

I tried a different code but ended up with

```
K = find(L(:,end)==J)    
ans = 9
```

---

The result I wanted was

```
K = [1 2 3
     4 5 6
     1 4 6] % This last row is now equal to J
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ...not sure what you want to do here. Can you add your desired output to the question text?

Comment: ...your desired result is the original matrix?

Comment: @user125918 well it still not clear. What do you want exactly, K seems to be like L

Comment: [Here's](https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html) an article by MathWorks that covers how matrix indexing works with lots of examples.

Comment: As this seems to be a basic Matlab question, it may be relevant to check the [Getting Started](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-matlab.html) manual.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it easily by taking a copy from `L`. Then replace it:

```
K = L;
K(end, :) = J;
```

The expected result is `K`.